# Differentiation.

Tags: calculus

I am unable to differentiate the following,
$$y=\frac{1}{x+1}+x$$

I obtained the expression for $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-(x^2+x+1)}{(x+1)^2} $$
The actual answer stated for an expression in my textbook $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{(x^2+2x)}{(x+1)^2} $$

I require assistance.

Comment: It is not even clear what you want to differentiate. Please do mathjax in this site and in the meantime use parentheses

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d\dfrac1{(x+1)}}{dx}+\dfrac{dx}{dx}=-\dfrac1{(x+1)^2}+1=?$$

Answer (score 3):

$$y=(x+1)^{-1}+x$$
$$y'=-1(x+1)^{-2}+1$$
$$y'=\frac{-1}{(x+1)^2}+1=\frac{(x^2+2x)}{(x+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

first we simplify to $$\frac{1}{x+1}+x=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x+1}$$ applying the quotient rule we get $$y'=\frac{(2x+1)(x+1)-(x^2+x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$
can you simplify this?

Comment: "Simplifying", in this case, looks more like "messing": the differential of the left side in the first line is, imo, way easier and almost immediate, whereas in the right side one needs the quotient rule and the outcome looks pretty ugly...

Answer (score 0):

We begin by simplifying $y$ as $y=\frac{1+x(x+1)}{(x+1)}$.

We then compute $y'$ using the quotient rule for differentiation which is:

$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow h'(x)=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$

Thus, $y'=\frac{(x+1)(2x+1)-(x^2+x+1)(1)}{(x+1)^2}$

Hence, $y'=\frac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ :

So, now finding derivative of  $\frac{1}{(x+1)}$ +$x$ is:

$\frac{d}{dx}$ $\frac{1}{(x+1)}$ +$\frac{dx}{dx}$

= -$\frac{\frac{d(x+1)}{dx}}{(x+1)^2}$ +1

= -$\frac{\frac{d(x)}{dx} + \frac{d(1)}{dx}}{(x+1)^2}$ +1

= 1 - $\frac{1 + 0}{(x+1)^2}$

= $\frac{(x+1)^2-1}{(x+1)^2}$

= $\frac{x^2 + 2x + 1 - 1}{(x+1)^2}$

= $\frac{x^2 + 2x}{(x+1)^2}$
 Hence the answer..

I hope this helps.